# How can I receive unknown fields in a WCF Data Contract?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have to develop a WCF service that should receive some predefined fields and some unknown fields. I would like to have a *Dictionary[string, object]* DataMember to receive this unknown fields but any solution that works will make me happy.

I have played around with IExtensibleDataObject and even managed to get the unknown fields in it but I was unsuccessful in accessing the data from it, only get to see them using the debugger. If anyone knows how I can access this data, please let me know.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should use ` for inline code ie. `Dictionary[string, object]`. Unless you had a reason for italics?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a property of type `Dictionary` and include this in your data contract?

```
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<string,object> ExtraFields { get; set; }
```

**Edit:** `ExtensibleDataObject` is meant for round-tripping scenarios, for this reason the members are not visible to the service. There are some [workarrounds](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2009/04/03/accessing-extended-data-from-iextensibledataobject.aspx), but I think it's better to do it explicit in another property.

Comment: Hi Akzent, I have tried but the field ExtraFields was not initialized, remained null. Should I have to set something else in order to use this technique?

Comment: You have to initalize and set the values explicit in the client to use this. It's not using any magic, just plain old WCF properties.

Comment: Sorry Akzent, I'm still not understanding what I have to do. Can you show me an example or a link that explains how to do this?

Comment: First, can you tell me what client you are using for this WCF service? Maybe you can post an example on how you call the webservice and the webservice method with the DataContract and I can tell you how to add the code necessary